# How to skip single line sql comment -- in antlr4

Tags: java, sql, antlr, antlr4

How do I skip sql single line comments in antlr4 grammar?

This is the input which I have given:

```
--
-- $INPUT.sql$
--


CREATE TABLE table_one ( customer_number integer, address character varying(30));

create table table_two ( id integer, city character varying(50));
```

Comment: Please post your entire grammar and a little driver class that shows the fact that `SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT` gobbles up your entire input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT
 : '--' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
 ;
```

If I parse your example input with the following grammar:

```
grammar Hello;

parse
 : .*? EOF
 ;

INTEGER
 : [0-9]+
 ;

IDENTIFIER
 : [a-zA-Z_]+
 ;

SINGLE_LINE_COMMENT
 : '--' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;

OTHER
 : .
 ;
```

and let ANTLRWorks2 print the tokens, I see the following:

```
[@0,23:28='CREATE',<2>,6:0]
[@1,30:34='TABLE',<2>,6:7]
[@2,36:44='table_one',<2>,6:13]
[@3,46:46='(',<5>,6:23]
[@4,48:62='customer_number',<2>,6:25]
[@5,64:70='integer',<2>,6:41]
[@6,71:71=',',<5>,6:48]
[@7,73:79='address',<2>,6:50]
[@8,81:89='character',<2>,6:58]
[@9,91:97='varying',<2>,6:68]
[@10,98:98='(',<5>,6:75]
[@11,99:100='30',<1>,6:76]
[@12,101:101=')',<5>,6:78]
[@13,102:102=')',<5>,6:79]
[@14,103:103=';',<5>,6:80]
[@15,106:111='create',<2>,8:0]
[@16,113:117='table',<2>,8:7]
[@17,119:127='table_two',<2>,8:13]
[@18,129:129='(',<5>,8:23]
[@19,131:132='id',<2>,8:25]
[@20,134:140='integer',<2>,8:28]
[@21,141:141=',',<5>,8:35]
[@22,143:146='city',<2>,8:37]
[@23,148:156='character',<2>,8:42]
[@24,158:164='varying',<2>,8:52]
[@25,165:165='(',<5>,8:59]
[@26,166:167='50',<1>,8:60]
[@27,168:168=')',<5>,8:62]
[@28,169:169=')',<5>,8:63]
[@29,170:170=';',<5>,8:64]
[@30,172:171='<EOF>',<-1>,9:0]
```

I.e.: the line comment are discarded properly. If it does not with happen in your case, something else is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry @BartKiers, I don't know why it doesn't worked before... Its working now...Thanks for your help.

Comment: ,That's ok... Am a newbie to antlr..Really thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

try `EOF` on the end of the rule as one of the options not just `\r\n`, like:

```
LINE_COMMENT
   : '//' ~[\r\n]* (EOF|'\r'? '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN)
   ;
```

Comment: getting the same result... Skipping the whole sql file

Comment: once try this code
`LINE_COMMENT
   : '--' ~[\r\n]* (EOF|'\r'? '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN)
   ;`

Comment: whats about `//` instead of `--` like, `LINE_COMMENT
  : '//' ~[\r\n]* (EOF|'\r'? '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN)  
  ;`

Comment: // works fine, am able to skip those comments..but -- comments doesn't working